# Use hard/soft constraint score at same time in drool/optaplanner

Tags: drools, optaplanner, drools-planner

Is it possible to use the hard and soft constraint score in the consequences part of a rule but one of them has a non-zero value. e.g.

```
scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, $weight * isHard);
scoreHolder.addSoftConstraintMatch(kcontext, $weight * isSoft);
```

where the isHard/isSoft one of them is 1 the other is zero.

The above always took the value of the last statement executed (which is the softconstraint)

Answer (score 2):

That is [a known issue in OptaPlanner 6.2.0 and lower](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/PLANNER-284). The problem lies in `AbstractScoreHolder` because it only take the rule id as a key, not the score level.

Comment: As of 6.3.0.CR2 (http://www.optaplanner.org/download/releaseNotes/releaseNotes6.3.html#_other_improvements, available soon), OptaPlanner will support multiple constraint matches in the consequences part of a Drools rule. See https://issues.jboss.org/browse/PLANNER-284 for more info.